# Airflow task retried after failure despite retries=0

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I have an Airflow environment running on Cloud Composer (3 `n1-standard-1` nodes; image version: `composer-1.4.0-airflow-1.10.0`; config override: core `catchup_by_default=False`; PyPI packages: `kubernetes==8.0.1`).

During a DAG run, a few tasks (all GKEPodOperators) failed due to airflow worker pod eviction. All of these tasks were set to `retries=0`. One of them was requeued and retried. Why would this happen when the task is set to 0 retries? And why would it only happen to one of the tasks?

Comment: Please add your DAG. Can't help with looking at the code.

Answer (score -1):

"airflow worker pod eviction" means that some pods needed more resources hence some pods were evicted.

To fix this you can use larger machine types or try to reduce the DAGs memory consumption.

Review his [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/troubleshooting-dags#task_fails_without_emitting_logs) to have a better view.